# Apparmor enforce mode prevents Firefox from starting

Tags: firefox, apparmor

Once I activate the Apparmor profile for Firefox (enforce mode), the browser refuses to start. Some message appears saying something about denied, unfortunately the message is not copyable. I copied the snippet below from syslog - I assume that apparmor prevents an operation that Firefox requires to start. How can I modify Apparmor so that Firefox starts? I use a persistent Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB drive. Thanks!

```
Nov 30 19:45:53 ubuntu kernel: [ 4963.449265] audit: type=1400 audit(1480531553.688:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="getattr" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}" name="upper/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so" pid=14399 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=999 ouid=0
```

Comment: That must be the reason why by default the system disables apparmor for firefox...